# Verizon CDN is really slow inside China

Tags: performance, azure, cdn

We have a production Azure web app that uses Verizon CDN (premium) for better performance, but the CDN performs really bad inside China. Sometimes the first load takes about 70 seconds to get delivered. What is more surprising is, if I disable using the CDN the website works faster.

I checked the CDN for cache HITs. They look fine. We have close to 99.4% HITs, also the requests are getting delivered from Edge nodes only. Has anyone experienced this issue? I am attaching a few performance screenshots.

Web performance 1:

[image: Web Performance 1]

Web performance 2:

[image: Web Performance 2]

Based on country:

[image: Based on Country]